# Objective-C, C type Arrays, and OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode, opengl-es

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this, or if it's been asked before...

So here we go:

I'm trying to write a game in Objective-C for iOS. One main feature of this game is the ability to morph the 2D landscape (technically 3D, however it starts out as a flat, 2D plain with points scattered throughout it to make a perfect mesh of 20 1x1 squares) to the user's liking; *however*, in Objective-C, apparently you cannot pass C-Typed arrays through methods.

e.g:

```
-(VertexS *) getVertexArrayData {
    VertexS myArray[definedAmount]; //VertexS being a structure
    for (int i = 0; i != definedAmount; i++) {
        myArray[i] = vertexData;
    }
    return *myArray;
}

//In the other file (the one with all my rendering), under a different class, inside a method
//Lets pretend the aforementioned method was under a class called "Terrain"
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     terrain = [[[Terrain alloc] init] autorelease];
     [terrain constructLand];
     VertexS *_vertexData = [terrain getVertexArrayData];
     ... etc.
}
```

Apparently, it doesn't work. Not saying that that is exactly what I'm doing, but very similar. What happens in my exact code is I use an ivar to hold the vertex/index data after it gets info from the other method.

Considering OpenGL (ES) requires either a vector container (well, in C++), or a C type Array (which is technically the same thing) in order to correctly create an IBO/VBO, I'm at a loss. I've been fiddling with it for almost a day and a half now, unable to get around the problem, and too (mentally) fat to learn NSMutableArrays--unless suggested by you, the wonderful community, in which I will pseudo-miraculously lose enough weight to learn NSMutableArrays (probably better said as "I will stop avoiding the unfamiliar solution,").

I can't actually remember my other question... Mreh. It probably isn't relavent but if I remember I will find a way to ask it.

Anyways, any help is requested. I don't know what else I can possibly do to get around this road block in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of the C language, so anything you can do in plain C will also work in Objective-C. The `myArray` array is declared on the stack in `-getVertexArrayData`. It gets abandoned when the method returns and that memory is available for reuse by the next function call. To fix this, allocate the array on the heap using `malloc()` (or one of its relatives).

```
-(VertexS *) getVertexArrayData {
    VertexS *myArray = malloc(definedAmount * sizeof(VertexS));
    for (int i = 0; i < definedAmount; i++) {
        myArray[i] = vertexData;
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

C-style memory management doesn't use reference counting, so don't forget to free the array when you're done with it:

```
free(_vertexData);
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!

Another issue though, when I try to sizeof() the returned array, it consistently returns only 4 bytes... Why is this?

Comment: That's the size of the pointer, not what it points to. `sizeof(*myArray) == sizeof(VertexS)`